# Characterization of Universal Measurablizers?

Tags: measure-theory

Ok, someone suggest a better title.

Someone recently asked [1. Measurable sets : uncountable union, 2. null set is disjoint from translated rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432794/1-measurable-sets-uncountable-union-2-null-set-is-disjoint-from-translated/1432819#1432819) about how to show that $A+[-1,1]$ was Lebesgue measurable for any Lebesgue measurable set $A$. I noticed that in fact $A+[-1,1]$ is Borel for *any* set $A$, measurable or not.

Which raises the curious question: What sets $E$ have the property that $A+E$ is (Lebesgue? Borel?) measurable for every $A$?

Comment: As you surely noted yourself, this holds for every open set $E$. Furthermore, any such set has to be Lebesgue/Borel measurable itself, as follows by taking $A=\{0\}$. Also, countable unions of sets having your property again have that property. One point sets do not satisfy your condition. But sadly, your class is not closed under complements... That were my immediate thoughts. Nice question!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I got that far myself...